# How to estimate tablespace size in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, block, tablespace

i want to Estimate tablespace and block size in Oracle DataBase when i expect records in each table from 100K to 500K ,
i cannot find equation or way to esstimate this point.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend a lot on your specific data, the number and type of indexes you have, and on things like use of compression and encryption of data at rest. There isn't a single one-size-fits-all formula to use. If your data is already stored somewhere else, use that as a guideline for the rough order of magnitude for the raw table data, then make your best guess on space required for indexes and leave room to grow based on the number and type of transactions you expect against the tables.

The trick is to give yourself just enough space to hold the data you have, plus room to grow in reasonably sized increments over time (you don't want to grow too often, so don't make the datafile auto expand increments too small).

You don't have to be super precise as far as Oracle is concerned. If you don't allocate enough space to start, your datafiles can grow over time as needed, or you can add more datafiles to your tablespace. If you allocate too much space to start, you can reduce the size of your datafiles so that you don't have a lot of empty space to backup for no reason.

Comment: I get that but what i don't understand is how to estimate the start tablespace size if i don't have my data stored somewhere but i know which data type i deal with in each table

Comment: You may have to take your best guess, especially if you don't have any data to begin with. Start small and adjust as you go.